# why does addProductToCart and HTMLElement.addCartClicked not defiend

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a website but I got some errors in my Javascript code. My errors are on lines 97 and line 65:

```
main.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener') at addProductToCart (main.js:97:53) at HTMLElement.addCartClicked (main.js:65:1)
addProductToCart(title,price,productImg);
cartShopBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-remove')[0].addEventListener('click',removeCartItem);
```

```js
// cart
let cartIcon = document.querySelector("#cart-icon");
let cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
let closeCart = document.querySelector("#close-cart");

//open cart
cartIcon.onclick = ()=>{
    cart.classList.add("active");
};
//close cart
closeCart.onclick = ()=>{
    cart.classList.remove("active");
};

if(document.readyState== 'loading'){
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",ready);
}else{
    ready();
}


function ready(){
    var removeCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-remove')
    console.log(removeCartButtons)
    for( var i =0;i<removeCartButtons.length;i++){
        var button = removeCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener("click" ,removeCartItem)
    }
    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')
    for( var i =0;i<quantityInputs.length;i++){
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change',quantityChanged);

    }
    var addCart = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart')
    for( var i =0;i<addCart.length;i++){
        var button = addCart[i]
        button.addEventListener('click',addCartClicked);

    }
}

function removeCartItem(event){
    var buttonClicked= event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.remove();
    updatetotal();
}

function quantityChanged(event){
    var input = event.target
    if(isNaN(input.value)|| input.value <= 0){
        input.value=1
    }
    updatetotal();  
}


function addCartClicked(event){
var button = event.target;
var shopProducts = button.parentElement;
var title = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-title')[0].innerText;
var price = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerText;
var productImg = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-img')[0].src;

addProductToCart(title,price,productImg);
updatetotal();
}

function addProductToCart(title ,price ,productImg){
    var cartShopBox = document.createElement('div');
    cartShopBox.classList.add('cart-box');
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
    var cartItemsNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-product-title');
    for( var i =0;i<cartItemsNames.length;i++){
        if(cartItemsNames[i].innerText==title){
    alert("You have already add this item to cart");
    return;
        }
    
}


var cartboxContent = `
<img src="${productImg}"  class="cart-img">
<div class="detail-box">
    <div class="cart-profuct-title">Nothing</div>
    <div class="cart-price">$5.04</div>
    <input type="number" value="1" class="cart-quantity">
</div>
<!-- Remove cart-->
<i class='bx bxs-trash cart-remove'></i>`;

cartShopBox.innerHtml = cartboxContent;

cartItems.append(cartShopBox);

cartShopBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-remove')[0].addEventListener('click',removeCartItem);
cartShopBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')[0].addEventListener('change',quantityChanged);
}

function updatetotal(){
    var  cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
    var cartBoxes = cartContent.getElementsByClassName('cart-box');
    var total =0
    for( var i =0;i<cartBoxes.length;i++){
        var cartBox =  cartBoxes[i];
        var priceElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
        var quantityElement= cartBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')[0];
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace("$",""));
        var quantity = quantityElement.value ;
        total = total +(price*quantity);
        //round the price
        total =  Math.round(total *100)/100;

        document.getElementsByClassName('total-price')[0].innerText='$'+total;
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,500&display=swap');
*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior-top: 2rem;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}


:root{
    --main-color: #fd4646;
    --text-color: #171427;
    --bg-color:#fff;
    
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    
}

body{
    color: var(--text-color);
}
.container{
    max-width: 1068px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

section{
    padding: 4rem 0 3rem;
    
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px hsl(0 4% 15% / 10% );
    z-index: 100;

}
.nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight:400;
}

#cart-icon{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor:pointer; 

}
.cart{
   position: fixed; 
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 360px;
   min-height: 100vh;
   padding: 20px;
   background: var(--bg-color);
   box-shadow: -2px 0 4px hsl(0 4% 15% / 10% );
   transition: 0.3s;
}
.cart.active{
    right: 0;
}
.cart-title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
.cart-box{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 32% 50% 18%;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.cart-img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: contain;
    padding: 10px;
}
.detail-box{
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 0.5rem;
}
.cart-profuct-title{
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.cart-price{
    font-weight: 500;
}
.cart-quantity{
    border: 1px solid var(--text-color);
    outline-color: var(--main-color);
    width: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.cart-remove{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: var(--main-color);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.total{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--text-color);

}
.total-title{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.total-price{
margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.btn-buy{
    display: flex;
    margin: 1.5rem auto 0 auto;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--bg-color);
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.btn-buy:hover{
    background: var(--text-color);
}
#close-cart{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 1rem;
font-size: 2rem;
color: var(--main-color) ;
cursor: pointer;
}
.section-title{
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     font-weight:600;
     text-align: center;
     margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.shop{
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.shop-content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(300px,auto));
    gap: 1.5rem;
    
}
.product-box{
    position: relative;
}
.product-box:hover{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid var(--text-color);
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.product-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.product-title{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.price{
    font-weight: 500;
}

.add-cart{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: var(--text-color);
    color: var(--bg-color);
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.add-cart:hover{
    background: hsl(249,32%,17%);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<!-- header-->
<header>
    <!-- nav-->

        <div class="nav container">
            <a href="#" class="logo">Donut Store</a>
            <!-- cart-icon-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag' id="cart-icon"></i>

        </div>
    <!-- cart-->
    <div class="cart">
        <h2 class="cart-title">Your Cart</h2>
        <!-- Content-->
        <div class="cart-content">

            <!-- Total-->
            <div class="total">
                <div class="total-title">Totale</div>
                <div class="total-price">$0</div>
            </div>
            <!-- Buy Button-->
            <button type="button" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</button>
            <!-- cart close-->
            <i class='bx bx-x 'id="close-cart"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>
        <!-- shop-->
<section class="shop-container">
     <h2 class="section-title">Shop products</h2>
        <!-- Content-->
     <div class="shop-content">

        <!-- Box 1-->
        <div class="product-box">
            <img src="donut1.png" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">Strawberry confetti</h2>
            <span class="price">$5</span>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart'></i>

        </div>
        <!-- Box 2-->
        <div class="product-box">
            <img src="donut2.png" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">Cinnamon Bun</h2>
            <span class="price">$3</span>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart'></i>

        </div>
        <!-- Box 3-->
        <div class="product-box">
            <img src="donut3.png" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">Midnight Madness</h2>
            <span class="price">$7</span>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart'></i>

        </div>
        <!-- Box 4-->
        <div class="product-box">
            <img src="donut4.png" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">The Flip Flop</h2>
            <span class="price">$4</span>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart'></i>

        </div>
        <!-- Box 5-->
        <div class="product-box">
            <img src="donut5.png" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">The Boardwalk</h2>
            <span class="price">$5</span>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart'></i>

        </div>
        <!-- Box 6-->
        <div class="product-box">
            <img src="donut6.png" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">Raspberry Fluff</h2>
            <span class="price">$5</span>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart'></i>

        </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please include your html to produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: i also put both line errors so you can see which one is that

Comment: your element does not exist yet. take the `cartShopbox` code at the bottom and add it inside your `ready` function.

Comment: i did it but stil same

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes in the `addProductToCart` function:

- innerHtml => innerHTML
- cardItems.append(cartShopBox) => cardItems.appendChild(cartShopBox)

This should be your function now:

```
function addProductToCart(title ,price ,productImg){
    var cartShopBox = document.createElement('div');
    cartShopBox.classList.add('cart-box');
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
    var cartItemsNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-product-title');
    for( var i =0;i<cartItemsNames.length;i++){
            console.log(cartItemsNames[i].innerText)
            if(cartItemsNames[i].innerText==title){
                    alert("You have already add this item to cart");
                    return;
            }
    }


    var cartboxContent = `
    <img src="${productImg}"  class="cart-img">
            <div class="detail-box">
            <div class="cart-profuct-title">Nothing</div>
            <div class="cart-price">$5.04</div>
            <input type="number" value="1" class="cart-quantity">
    </div>
    <!-- Remove cart-->
    <i class='bx bxs-trash cart-remove'></i>`;

    cartShopBox.innerHTML = cartboxContent;

    cartItems.appendChild(cartShopBox);
    cartShopBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-remove')[0].addEventListener('click',removeCartItem);
    cartShopBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')[0].addEventListener('change',quantityChanged);
}
```

Comment: i put }  before updatetotal() begin

Comment: if u can run the code in your pc , my code inculde html css javascript

Comment: Sorry your code in Stackoverflow was not very clear where the function ended but I updated the answer and i should work now.